# Why the order of a written dataframe is not kept after reading it?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am writing a dataframe to HDFS ordering by the first two columns:

```
final = <dataframe>.select('Pais','Anho','NumPatentes','TotalCitas','MediaCitas','MaxCitas').orderBy("Pais", "Anho")

final.show()
final.write.format("csv").save("<path>", header = 'true')
```

Then I am reading it from the HDFS using:

```
a = (spark \
.read \
.option("inferSchema", "true") \
.option("header", "true") \
.csv("<path>")).show()
```

However, the output of the first `show()` is not equal to the second one. I mean, first dataframe shown is ordered and second one is not. These are the first and the second dataframes:

```
+-------------+----+-----------+----------+----------+--------+
|         Pais|Anho|NumPatentes|TotalCitas|MediaCitas|MaxCitas|
+-------------+----+-----------+----------+----------+--------+
|        Italy|1970|          1|         3|       3.0|       3|
|        Italy|1980|          2|         3|       1.5|       2|
|        Italy|1983|          2|         4|       2.0|       2|
|United States|1978|          1|         1|       1.0|       1|
+-------------+----+-----------+----------+----------+--------+
+-------------+----+-----------+----------+----------+--------+
|         Pais|Anho|NumPatentes|TotalCitas|MediaCitas|MaxCitas|
+-------------+----+-----------+----------+----------+--------+
|United States|1978|          1|         1|       1.0|       1|
|        Italy|1980|          2|         3|       1.5|       2|
|        Italy|1970|          1|         3|       3.0|       3|
|        Italy|1983|          2|         4|       2.0|       2|
+-------------+----+-----------+----------+----------+--------+
```

It seems like the written dataframe is saved unordered. How can I solve this? How can I save it ordered?

Comment: spark does not read/write data in order, you need to mentioned order by again in Reading data from HDFS. That's why it is not recommended to use order by in spark. If you want data in particular order then you can ignore order by before write and use it once during reading back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Saving ordered dataframe in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41364540/saving-ordered-dataframe-in-spark)

[Do Spark/Parquet partitions maintain ordering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55054306/do-spark-parquet-partitions-maintain-ordering)

based on these answers, you cannot maintain order during the write of files, since the partitions are written, and read separately and spark only guarantee sorting inside a partition.